# Sharpe ratio 1 and probability to lose money

Tags: sharpe-ratio, strategy

I came across the following interview problem and I am looking for a possible solution. We have a strategy with risk free return 0 and sharpe ratio 1. What is the probability to lose money over four years ?

Comment: I tried the following : if $r_i$ is the daily return, I am looking for $S = P(\sum_{~1000}r_i < 0)$ approximating the four years to 1.000 days. Sharpe ratio of 1 gives me that $E(r) = \sigma$. I am trying to use the central limit theorem yielding $\frac{S-nE(r)}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$ is approximately $N(0, 1)$. I am stuck on how to use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume annual returns, because that's usually how the Sharpe ratio is stated. Let's assume returns are normally distributed and independent with mean $\mu > 0$. Then $R_i \sim{\mathcal{N}(\mu, \mu^2)}$ for $i = 1, 2, 3, 4$. Because of my independence assumption, $\sum_{i = 1}^4 R_i \sim{\mathcal{N}(4\mu, 4\mu^2)}$.  The $Z$-score corresponding to 0 is $Z = \frac{0 - 4\mu}{2\mu} = -2$. Hence,
$$
P\left(\sum_{i = 1}^4 R_i \leq 0\right) = P\left(Z \leq -2\right) \approx 2.28\%.
$$